# issue with second activity onActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have my code of first activity:
[image: ProfileActivity]

and a second activity:
[image: GalleryActivity]
but I am not sure why the part "onActivityResult" is not functioning to show the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting Gallery Activity incorrectly in on Click callback in first Activity. In order to start one Activity from the other, you should use startActivity method, instead of instantiating object:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, GalleryActivity.class));
```

Comment: I replaced the 'new GalleryActivity();' as 'startActivity(new Intent(this, GalleryActivity.class));'

Comment: but now it shows errors as  'error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<GalleryActivity>)
                startActivity(new Intent(this, GalleryActivity.class));
                              ^
    constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
    constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)'